# How to create a nested array inside an array in a json with Java?

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson

I am trying to figure out how to create a nested array inside an array with Java. See below:

```
{
    "fruit": [
        "apple"
    ],
    "color": [
        [                         <------ trying this!
            "red",
            "green"
        ]                         <------ trying this?
    ],
    "edible": true
}
```

But I only managed to do this:

```
{
    "fruit": [
        "apple"
    ],
    "color": [
        "red",
        "green"
    ],
    "edible": true
}
```

And so far... this is the code I have:

> Class with logic to create the json object

```
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class FruitInventory {

    public List<String> fruit;
    public List<String> color;
    private String edible;

    public FruitInventory() {
    }

    public FruitInventory(List<String> fruit, List<String> color, String edible) {
        this.fruit = fruit;
        this.color = color;
        this.edible = edible;
    }

    @JsonProperty("fruit")
    public List<String> getfruit() {
        return fruit;
    }

    @JsonProperty("fruit")
    public void setfruit(List<String> fruit) {
        this.fruit = fruit;
    }

    @JsonProperty("color")
    public List<String> getcolor() {
        return color;
    }

    @JsonProperty("color")
    public void setcolor(List<String> color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    @JsonProperty("edible")
    public String getedible() {
        return edible;
    }

    @JsonProperty("edible")
    public void setedible(String edible) {
        this.edible = edible;
    }

}
```

> Method to print json

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    FruitInventory fruitInventory = new FruitInventory();
    String json;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    List<String> fruit = new ArrayList<>();
    fruit.add("apple")

    List<String> color = new ArrayList<>();
    color.add("red");
    color.add("green");

    fruitInventory.setColumnNames(fruit);
    fruitInventory.setValues(color);

    json = mapper.writeValueAsString(fruitInventory);
    System.out.println(json);
}
```

I am not sure if I should create an empty array list inside `color` or how this will fit into my code example. If someone could suggest what to do and I would prefer if you take/modify my code as appropriate as it would be easier/make more sense to me. Appreciate any help, thanks! :)

Comment: The required structure is `List<List<String>> color`.

Comment: As Nikolas has said, you will have to change the `color` property to `List<List<String>>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `public List<String> color;` to `public List<List<String>> color;` as per your json structure.

Logic to populate it:

```
List<String> color = new ArrayList<>();
color.add("red");
color.add("green");

fruitInventory.setValues( Arrays.asList(color));
```

Comment: Seems right suggestion. Any idea about the exceptions I am getting after this change: Incompatible types.
Required: List <java.util.List<java.lang.String>> || Found: List <java.lang.String>

Comment: Did you change parameter type from list to listOfList in that constructor?

Comment: Change your constructor signature from `public FruitInventory(List<String> fruit, List<String> color, String edible)` to `public FruitInventory(List<String> fruit, List<List<String>> color, String edible)`